# Create the following list [1, 2, [3, 4], [3, [4, 5]]] in Haskell

Tags: haskell, nested-lists

I'm trying to make a list that contains sub lists, like `[1, 2, [3, 4], [3, [4, 5]]]`.

It seems like I should define a new type. I tried:

```
data NestedList a = Int a | List [NestedList a]
```

but I think its wrong, or that I don't know how to use it. I'm very new to Haskell and I'm not sure about the meaning of this expression.

Does it mean that it is making a "type" `Int` with parameter `a` and a "type" `List` with parameter `[NestedList a]`?

The `data` expression above was taken from the [solution](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/Solutions/7) to the 7th exercise of the [99 Haskell questions](https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/1_to_10)

> (**) Flatten a nested list structure.
>
> ```
> data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]
>
> flatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
> flatten (Elem x) = [x]
> flatten (List x) = concatMap flatten x
> ```

but when I call `flatten [[1,2], 3]` in `ghci` I get the error of

```
couldn't match expected type 'NestedList a0' with actual type '[t0]'
```

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113238/is-it-true-ask-jelly/113416#113416

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't call `flatten [[1,2],3]` because your flatten should take a `NestedList a`, not a nested normal list, which isn't even allowed in Haskell.

Your call should be something like

```
flatten (List [Elem 3, List [Elem 2, Elem 4], Elem 5])
```

Comment: He is saying that `[[1,2],3]` is not the same type as `NestedList` in haskell even though the appear the same just as `data MyInt = Int` is not the same as `Int`.  And his other point `[1,2]` is a list of `Num` and `3` is a Num so `[[1,2],3]` isn't even allowed because `[1,2]` is not the same type as `3`.

Comment: when i write :t [1,2,[3]] i get [1,2,[3]] :: (Num t ,Num [t]) => [[t]]   but i dont know how to make  a new type that allows me to have such a list.

Comment: Having something like `[1,2,3]` is just some special syntactic sugar for writing `1 : 2 : 3 : []` and i don't think you can use that `[1,2,3]` notation for your own data types. Now for the data type you defined, there are two constructors, `List` and `Elem`. md2perpe already showed an example how to use those. If you want a piece of data that represents something like `[[1,2],3]` (which you can't make with normal lists) you write `List [ List [ Elem 1, Elem 2 ], Elem 3 ]`

Comment: @user2254424 Just make `[t]` an instance of `Num`. One way can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/5339971 What happens is that `1` and `2` in `[1,2,[3]]` get converted to `[1]` viz `[2]` by `fromInteger`, so that you end up with the list `[[1],[2],[3]]`.

Answer (score 8):

This is a side note that I couldn't fit in a comment.  This does not directly answer your question but I thought you might find it useful.

Your type is the same as a `Forest`.  See `Data.Tree` in the `containers` package, which [implements this type](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Tree.html#t:Forest) for you.

It even includes a `flatten` function:

```
flatten :: Tree a -> [a]
```

... which you can make work for a `Forest` too just by using `concatMap`:

```
concatMap flatten :: Forest a -> [a]
```