# Simplifying Nested List input in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm making a function to flatten a nested list of arbitrary depth.

flatten.hs

```hs
data NestedList a = Regular a | Nested [NestedList a]

flatten::NestedList a -> [a]
flatten (Regular a) = [a]
flatten (Nested a) = concatMap flatten a
```

Right now if I want to flatten the list `[1,2,3,[1,[1, 2]],2]`I have to input it like `(Nested [Regular 1, Regular 2, Regular 3, Nested [Regular 1, Nested [Regular 1, Regular 2]], Regular 2])`. Is there a way to simplify the input value? I know about `OverloadedLists` but have no idea how to work with them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create the following list \[1, 2, \[3, 4\], \[3, \[4, 5\]\]\] in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884984/create-the-following-list-1-2-3-4-3-4-5-in-haskell)

Comment: make it `data NestedList a = A a | L [NestedList a]` (for "atom" and "list" a-la Lisp) and it becomes almost bearable to write `L[A 1,A 2,A 3,L[A 1,L[A 1, A 2]],A 2]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get part-way there with `OverloadedLists`:

The key here is defining an `IsList` instance.  With overloaded lists, if GHC sees something like:

```
[x,y,z]
```

and can parse `x`, `y`, `z` as all the same type `item`, then it will put them into a list `[x,y,z] :: [item]` and call:

```
fromList :: [item] -> NestedList a
```

You have to choose the right definition of `item` to get this to work.  And, since you want to be able to write:

```
[[another_nested_list],[another_nested_list]]
```

with the inner lists parsed exactly the same way, it turns out you need `item` to be `NestedList a`, too:

```
fromList :: [NestedList a] -> NestedList a
```

This gives the `IsList` instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

import GHC.Exts

data NestedList a = Regular a | Nested [NestedList a] deriving (Show)

instance IsList (NestedList a) where
  type Item (NestedList a) = NestedList a
  fromList = Nested
```

With this in place, you can write:

```
> flatten [Regular 1, Regular 2, Regular 3, [Regular 1, [Regular 1, Regular 2]], Regular 2]
[1,2,3,1,1,2,2]
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work without the `Regular`s because `1` can't be parsed as an `item`, namely `NestedList a`.

You can play a dirty trick by defining a `Num` instance to parse the integer literal into a `NestedList a` like so:

```
instance (Num a) => Num (NestedList a) where
  fromInteger = Regular . fromInteger
```

and that'll let you write:

```
flatten [1,2,3,[1,[1,2]],2]
> [1,2,3,1,1,2,2]
```

That gets it working with integers only.  If you try to write:

```
> flatten [[1.5,2.5]]
> flatten [["bar"],[["foo"]]
```

you'll get errors.  You'd need to define a `Fractional` instance to handle `1.5` and an `IsString` instance (using `OverloadedStrings`) to handle `"bar"`.